# Create a function to check if the quantity inserted is greater than the quantity in stock

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails](
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UnitPrice] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Discount] [int] NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want to create a function which will check if the quantity inserted is greater then the quantity in stock then prevents user from execution.

Comment: Think about which `SELECT` would give you the right response... then add it to your app.

Answer (score 0):

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.PreventQtyInsert ON dbo.OrderDetails
AFTER INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @returnQuantity               INT ,
                @Quantity                     INT ,
                @ProductID                    INT ,
                @GetQuantityFromProductsTable INT;

```
    SELECT @returnQuantity = dbo.ReturnUnitsInStock ( @Quantity , @ProductID ) ;

    IF @returnQuantity = 0
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ( 'This vendor''s credit rating is too low to accept new purchase orders.' , 16 , 1 ) ;
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            RETURN;
        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN

            SET @GetQuantityFromProductsTable = ( SELECT UnitsInStock FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID ) ;
            UPDATE OrderDetails SET Quantity = @GetQuantityFromProductsTable - @Quantity
            WHERE ProductID = @ProductID;


        END;

END;
```

GO